# Integrating agora RTM SDK in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io

I'm trying to get the provided sample app from the agora's site: https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/run_rtm_unity?platform=Unity. And following their instruction gives me infintie import loop on macOS with unity version 2020.1.6f1 which is less that their claimed version 2020.3 having issues on mac. But, I also tried on linux and windows, they still have one or more errors, like missing dlls or simply crash without warning.

I basically want to build a chat section into my app, and the documentation to me seems a bit outdated, this is my project structure so far. Notice the RTM scripts is a bit misplaced with regards to the instruction on the documentation, that's because the sample app seems to expect it in that place, and once I import the `Plugins` folder as mentioned in the instruction to integrate the SDK, I get an infinite import loop:

[image]
If anyone has used this please let me know how to integrate the chat(not the video) SDK in unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloning of the repository fails, but, the `.unitypackage`  seems to work even in 2020.3 version of unity and macOS dev env. The package is available here: https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-Unity-RTM-SDK/releases . Just double click and import. It produces some GUID errors, so please comment if someone has fixed these GUID conflict issues.